# mysql - how to run query without index

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, database-indexes

I am looking to compare indexes and further optimize my code.  What I would like to do is force the query to run without an index so I can see what difference it has made.  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can ask the query to not use indexes by adding `IGNORE INDEX (index1, index2, ...)` to your query. More details can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html).

*Note:* I know this is an old question and you would already have found the answer, but I hope this will help others looking for the same answer, and they wouldn't have to spend their valuable time digging through the MySQL docs.